# Rupture field of $X^p+T$ equals its splitting field

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field of prime characteristic $p$. Let $P(X)=X^p+T$ be a polynomial from $K(T)[X]$. $P$ is irreducible over $K(T)$ by Eisenstein criterion. Show that a rupture field of $P$ is also a splitting field.

Comment: I have never heard the term, "rupture field." Does that just mean a field in which $p$ has a root?

Comment: Rupture field is an extension generated by a root of P. For irreducible polynomials, it is unique up to an isomorphism.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  [Rupture field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupture_field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure about the starting point: a splitting field is the smallest field extension, such that the polynomial splits and a rupture field is a field extension generated by a single root.

In this case, there is one observation that seems to solve the question, namely $$(X+\sqrt[p]{T})^p = X^p+T+p\cdot(\ldots). $$
Since $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$, the latter terms vanish and $(X+\sqrt[p]{T})^p = X^p+T$ remains. By adjoining $\sqrt[p]{T}$ we thus get a splitting field of $P$ over $K(T)$ and this is also a rupture field.

Comment: Thanks. I should had been more patient with this one.